# How to set margin dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, margins

I am currently doing an android application that contains customize alert dialog. It contains  a button , but i can't set the margin for the button . the code is given below. setmargin method is not working

```
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
Button button = new Button(Login.this);

button.setText("Send");
LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams 
    = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

button.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);

resetPassword=editText.getText().toString();

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(Login.this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.addView(textView);
layout.addView(editText);
layout.addView(button);

myDialog.setView(layout);
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Write below code to set margin, it may help you.

```
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
Button button = new Button(Login.this);
EditText editText = new EditText(Login.this);
TextView textView = new TextView(Login.this);
button.setText("Send");
LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
buttonLayoutParams.setMargins(50, 10, 0, 0);
button.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
String resetPassword = editText.getText().toString();
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(Login.this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.addView(textView);
layout.addView(editText);
layout.addView(button);
myDialog.setView(layout);
myDialog.show();
```

Use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` or `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` according to parent layout of the child view

Comment: no it is not working. it shows an error  add cast to  buttonlayoutparams in setMargin method.

Comment: Please Import import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams; in your activity.

Answer (score 6):

Just sharing a slightly different approach.

Instead of casting to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, etc, you can just cast to `MarginLayoutParams`.

Casting to `MarginLayoutParams` is better because you can later update your layout and you don't need to return to your java code to change from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` or any other Layout type

You can do something like:

```
MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

// Set bottom margin
layoutParams.bottomMargin = x;

// Set top margin
layoutParams.topMargin = x;

// Set left margin
// This won't have effect if you set any relative margin (start) previously or in the layout.xml
layoutParams.leftMargin = x;

// Set left margin
// This won't have effect if you set any relative margin (end) previously or in the layout.xml
layoutParams.rightMargin = x;

// Set start margin
layoutParams.setMarginStart(x);

// Set end margin
layoutParams.setMarginStart(x);

// Set all left, top, right, bottom margins at once
// Note that here, left and right margins are set (not start/end).
// So, if you have used start/end margin before (or via layout.xml), 
// setting left/right here won't have any effect.
layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, end, bottom)

// Then re-apply the layout params again to force the view to be re-draw
// This step may not be necessary because depending where you set the margin, 
// view is already scheduled to be drawn
// For any case, to ensure the view will apply the new margin, call:
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
buttonLayoutParams.bottomMargin
buttonLayoutParams.topMargin
buttonLayoutParams.leftMargin
buttonLayoutParams.rightMargin
```

can be used to set margins

Comment: Are you setting the layout parameters for your `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

The setMargin() method is available if you're using LinearLayout.LayoutParams but not if you're using ViewGroup.LayoutParams. Dipak Keshariya alludes to this but doesn't say it in so many words.

Answer (score 2):

```
You can set in LinearLayout margin

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
Button okButton=new Button(this);
okButton.setText("some text");
ll.addView(okButton, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (The support library (need to use AndroidX):

Kotlin

```
val params = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
               ).apply {
                 setMargins(0,16,0,16)
               }
```

Java

```
LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams params = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                   )
                   params.setMargins(0,16,0,16)
```