# Why is setMargins not working with my RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout inside of another Relative Layout.When i use the inner layout to be LinearLayout the code works fine however.I read about many such [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062187/how-to-set-margin-dynamically-in-android) here on SO.Sometimes it was mentioned that the layout params used should be of the parent layout. I wasnt able to quite understand it.Is this where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance guys !

**MY XML FILE**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/rel1"  >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/helo" />

     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Function Where I use margins**

```
public void showcopter()
     {
          ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);           
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)(image.getLayoutParams());
          lp.leftMargin =0;//(int)((width-150)*density);
          lp.topMargin=(int)(hg-(30*density));   //hg is a global variale which stores the screen height
     //   Log.d("hello_girl",hg+" ");
     //   lp.setMargins((int) ((width-150)*density),(int)(hg-(30*density)),0,0);   
          image.setLayoutParams(lp);
          image.requestLayout();
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have set android:layout_alignParentRight to be true, leftMargin won't take effect, and while you set android:layout_centerVertical to be true, topMargin won't take effect either.

Comment: Yeah it worked thanks. Just copy pasted the code thats why it happened.Thanks.